# Incorrect data in the Tradingview Strategy Tester

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I noticed that the data in the strategy tester is different from the information on the chart. Here is an example and its screenshot.
Entry to "Long" 2023-07-13 15:00, exit 2023-07-15 07:00. The List of Deals shows the result +2.47%, while the chart shows that the result is 6.65%.

screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/fJOdU6o.png

I wonder what it might be related to?

Comment: Please use another host to upload your image.

Comment: I see everything well. Check [this](https://i.imgur.com/6PhD69z.png)